# Impossible to combine static routes & static pages generation in astro

Tags: astrojs

I'm working on a project astro based and I try to do the following:

1 - I create a astro page [productPage].astro

2 - In this page I have the following code

```
import data from "../data/data.json";
import { processTitle } from "../utils/stringUtils.js";

export function getStaticPaths() {

  const paths = data.products.map((product) => ({
  params: {
    productPage: processTitle(product.title, product.id)
  }
}));

  return paths;
}
const { productPage } = Astro.params;
```

This works (and astro generate a several pages with a nice name like `my-title-1`, `my-title-2`, `my-title-3`, `my-title-4` - 2 being the ID product) but every page has the same content.
Doing this allows me do change the string used for route name (for SEO purposes) without going to change the code everywhere (because I have other pages where I need the route name as link.

The rest of the page has this code

```
<ProductPageDetail
          title={data.products[0].title}
          minPrice={data.products[0].minPrice}
          images={data.products[0].images}
          colors={data.products[0].colors}
          description={data.products[0].description}
          data={data.products[0].data}
          type={data.products[0].types}
        />
```

3 - What I want is to replace the `products[0]` with the product values for the current page (like I said above I will have one page generated per product values).
If I had to name my page `[id].astro`, the same variable I could have used to get the product per `id` but since I have a transformed page name, not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was very simple, I found the answer.
I modified getStaticPaths like the following

```
export function getStaticPaths() {

  const paths = data.products.map((product) => ({
  params: {
    productPage: processTitle(product.title, product.id)    
  },
  props: {
    myproduct: product
  }
}));

  return paths;
}
```

Then to access that object

```
const {myproduct} = Astro.props;
```

So the code to render the product values

```
<ProductPageDetail
          title="ddssds"
          minPrice={myproduct.minPrice}
          images={myproduct.images}
          colors={myproduct.colors}
          description={myproduct.description}
          data={myproduct.data}
          type={myproduct.types}
        />
```